# jQuery UI Dialog reloading window in firefox

Tags: firefox, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a web app I am developing an running with firefox. I am using jQuery for several things, with several modal windows being part of that. With one of those modal dialogs, when a function is run, it changes the title, adds a button, then opens. When this function is run in firefox the window/tab will go blank for a brief moment, then the page will reappear and the dialog will display as expected. This doesn't affect functionality at all, just the presentation (i.e. It looks bad..). I suspect that what is happening is the DOM is being updated, causing firefox to quickly reload the page. What is causing this I don't know (outside of it being the jQuery dialog) and it doesn't do it with other dialogs I have on the same page.

The code that receives data, populates it into the dialog div, and opens the dialog:

```
else if(response.getElementsByTagName('reply')[0].firstChild.data == 'section') {
                var secContent = ''
                for(var i=0; i<response.getElementsByTagName('content').length;i++) {
                    secContent += response.getElementsByTagName('content')[i].firstChild.data;
                }
                document.getElementById('section').innerHTML = secContent;
                var section = response.getElementsByTagName('section')[0].firstChild.data;
                var pid = response.getElementsByTagName('pid')[0].firstChild.data;
                document.getElementById('loader_'+section).style.display = 'none';
                $("#section").dialog("option", "title", section.toUpperCase());
                $("#section").dialog("option", "buttons", { "Save Changes": function() { saveSec(section, pid); } } );
                $("#section").dialog("open");
            }
```

And the dialog box js:

```
$( "#section" ).dialog({
        minHeight: 300,
        minWidth: 500,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        show:'drop',
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you could try and isolate your problem as much as possible? Only then it is possible for others to test. I tried your code, stripped, and that worked (ie your problem didn't show up). Secondly, why don't you use jQuery some more? (document.getElementById('loader_'+section).style.display = 'none' could be $("#loader_"+section).hide()...

Comment: I commented out the two dialog lines, and just left the one that opens it, and it still happens. I even tried initializing the dialog within that function, and it happens. I tried initializing the dialog with the button already there and then changing it and it still happens. It seems just calling the open event on this "#section" dialog is causing the problem. As far as using more jquery I just haven't looked into it much outside of the UI components and don't know all of the capabilities.

Comment: CORRECTION: Isolated the problem to this line:
document.getElementById('section').innerHTML = secContent;
Seems changing the html content of the dialog's div is causing it to happen, not something within jQuery... It's still a DOM updating/Firefox issue, but it's not jQuery causing it. hmmmmm

Comment: actually it is the innerHTML replacement that is causing it to happen, but it doesn't happen until the dialog open even is triggered...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...
The html code the function was getting and inserting into the dialog div contained the problem. For some reason, which I haven't been able to solve, using the "selected" attribute for an "option" tag in a select drop down was causing it to happen. I have no idea why and it makes no sense to me, but removing the selected attribute made it pop up the dialog without a reload.